# Laravel detaching HasManyThrough relationships with ease

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.7

**SCENARIO**
Let's say that there's a system where companies could add other companies to their list of favorites. To fetch this record I would do something like the following:

```
// Returns a list of favorite companies for the current user's company 
$user->company()->favorites;
```

Note that the `favorites` represent the hasManyThrough relationship.

```
public function favorites()
{
  return $this->hasManyThrough(Company::class, CompanyFavorite::class, 'company_id_owner', 'id', 'id', 'company_id_selected');
}
```

**IDEAL SOLUTION** I'm looking for a solution where I could remove the record from the intermediary relationship table making use of the `hasManyThrough` object. Example:

```
$user->company()->favorites()->detach([...companies_ids]);
```

Comment: This could help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21149164/how-to-detach-one-instance-from-multiple-in-a-laravel-eloquent-pivot-table

Comment: Please post the `favorites` relationship.

Comment: @senty thank you but unfortunately I couldn't make much use of it as it works differently.
@JonasStaudenmeir I have added the `favorites` relationship above.

Answer (score 0):

`HasManyThrough` is not the right relationship here, use [`BelongsToMany`](https://laravel.com/docs/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) instead:

```php
public function favorites()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(
        Company::class, 'company_favorites', 'company_id_owner', 'company_id_selected'
    );
}
```

This relationship [provides](https://laravel.com/docs/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships) all the necessary methods like `attach()` and `detach()`:

```php
$user->company()->favorites()->detach([...companies_ids]);
```